# Presence of one Div causes another div to be visibile

Tags: css

So this may sound a little strange but I am trying to customize a pre-made journal platform and I want to cause one div with an ID to be visible when a completely separate div with a ID is present and I'm not sure how to write that CSS, or if it's even possible.  I can't really use javascript.

So basically if X div is present then Y div display: inline otherwise y div display:none;

Does that makes sense?  Is it possible?

So here's how the HTML looks:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="pdfViewer"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When "pdfViewer" is present I want to turn on "sidebar".

Comment: This isn't possible using just CSS, you'll have to use JS or some other scripting language to accomplish logic-based styles.

Comment: If i understand the question correctly, you can use selectors to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

`#X #Y` if Y is a child somewhere

`#X > #Y` if Y is a direct child

`#X + #Y` if Y is an adjacent sibling

`#X ~ #Y` if multiple Y's are present after X

If I understand you correctly, this should work because the Y's will match with `display: inline;` only when `#X` is present, otherwise you set `#Y` to `display: none;` as the default

Comment: Darn that's close.  In the pre-made html hierarchy that I can't change Y (the one I want to turn on and off) comes first but is not an adjacent sibling

Comment: Yeah CSS selectors only look ahead not backwards. So if you cannot find a hook ahead of Y that would serve your use case this might be impossible without Javascript. Now that you've edited the question to include the markup this is clear.